# how to identify that which android os user device is using?

Tags: android, device

i want to check the version of android operating system installed on user device.
can i find it using android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES or something else.
please provide code.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Please show what did you try so far and what's the issue with it. Also, this is quite a basic requirement so even if you do a simple google search, you will get the solution.

Comment: ok will take care next time @ prerak sola

Answer (score 1):

As described on Android Documentation API level can be retrieved using

[android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

The class corresponding to this int is in the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES class.

**Code example:**

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

Log.d("sdk version",""+currentapiVersion );


if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}
```

Comment: This **SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash**

Comment: Thanks @ Emdad Hossain

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`
To check if device is running Android lollipop or above :

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  // do something
}
```

Details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Answer (score 0):

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` tells you the API level that the device runs, which is usually all that a developer will need.

There are other fields [on `Build.VERSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) that may be of interest to you, if your goal is to display that information to users.